# Why can't Google Webmaster verify my websites subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, google-search-console

Okay, so I have my main site, `www.mydomain.com.au` along with my mobile site which is within a subdomain, `m.mydomain.com.au`.

I am trying to submit my subdomain to Google Webmaster Tools, although it cannot seem to verify it. I have tried with the HTML file upload and the meta tag option to.

I can verify that the Google HTML file is DEFINITELY uploaded since the link Google provides to check if it is there is working perfectly. Also, I have checked my source code and the meta tag is also definitely there.

My `.htaccess` file has a mobile redirect so I thought that may have been the problem, so I deleted that file to check if it would validate, but still no luck.

I have approximately 12 websites that are setup the EXACT same as this one, and all of their mobile sites/subdomains verified with Webmaster Tools perfectly.

This is my error message: `We were unable to connect to your server.`

Does anyone have any suggestions to why Google cannot verify my mobile site?

Comment: Is your main domain verified?

Comment: And then you tried to add m.domain.com as a new site and it didn't work correct? And have you tried www.m.domain.com and then setting m.domain.com as preferred URL?

Comment: @Prix `www.m.domain.com` does not link to anything since it is invalid.

Comment: Well I am assuming its failing because it tries to verify if the code at www.m.domain.com/google91283018301.html instead of m.domain.com but you could use the DNS verification and see if that passes.

Comment: @Prix - Yeah I was considering the DNS verification.. Althouh I believe that my provider charges for DNS access.

Comment: What is your hosting company for your domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't see sub domains...they see the folder where the sub domain is located.  Delete the site and add is again as mydomain.com.au/m

Google will see it and add it to Webmaster tools...I just did this for my sub domain. That's how I worked it out...

Answer (score 1):

You can verify them from here https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?hl=en

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Since the question is about Google Webmaster fizzix is probably aware of that link anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong that google is not seeing sub domains. you can check it with site:yoururl. with your main domain you will get your sub domain as well.